# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not TimeStamp - Python

Tags: python, datetime

Facing issues while converting date to string,

```
import datetime
Created_Date = booking_data['CreatedDate']
Requested_Date = booking_data['RequestedDate']

dt_string = Created_Date[0]
format_ = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
dt_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, format_)
```

I receive this Type Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-54c5c12a0039> in <module>
      7 dt_string = Created_Date[0]
      8 format_ = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
----> 9 dt_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, format_)

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: dt_string is not a string, its whatever a `Timestamp` object is. Question needs more details as to what this "Timestamp" object is.

Comment: Maybe just convert both to string with `str()`?

Comment: To find out what you have, you can use for example `dir(Created_Date[0])`. I'd *assume* it's coming from pandas, so you would be able to call `Created_Date[0].to_pydatetime()` to get an ordinary datetime object.